# Cannot install opencv-contrib-python with nonfree option

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, pip

I am trying to install opencv-contrib-python with the nonfree option:
`LANG=CC MAKEFLAGS="-j8" CMAKE_ARGS="-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON" pip install -v --no-binary=opencv-contrib-python opencv-contrib-python`

Unfortunately, I need this option for using SURF features of opencv (is there maybe a better way than SURF, which does not need the NONFREE option?)

My call results in the following error. Any ideas how to fix that?

My packages:

```
python 3.10.2
pip 22.0.4
opencv 4.5.5-3
```

The output of pip:

```
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/conv_spv.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/staticSaliencySpectralResidual.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/dw_conv_spv.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/lrn_spv.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/max_pool_spv.cpp.o
  In file included from /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:50:
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:542:5: error: 'AVBSFContext' does not name a type; did you mean 'AVIOContext'?
    542 |     AVBSFContext* bsfc;
        |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        |     AVIOContext
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'void CvCapture_FFMPEG::init()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:589:5: error: 'bsfc' was not declared in this scope
    589 |     bsfc = NULL;
        |     ^~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'void CvCapture_FFMPEG::close()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:620:34: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
    620 |         avcodec_close( video_st->codec );
        |                                  ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:655:9: error: 'bsfc' was not declared in this scope
    655 |     if (bsfc)
        |         ^~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:658:9: error: 'av_bsf_free' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'av_opt_free'?
    658 |         av_bsf_free(&bsfc);
        |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
        |         av_opt_free
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: At global scope:
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:803:39: error: 'AVLockOp' has not been declared
    803 | static int LockCallBack(void **mutex, AVLockOp op)
        |                                       ^~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function 'int LockCallBack(void**, int)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:808:14: error: 'AV_LOCK_CREATE' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'AV_LOG_TRACE'?
    808 |         case AV_LOCK_CREATE:
        |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |              AV_LOG_TRACE
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:817:14: error: 'AV_LOCK_OBTAIN' was not declared in this scope
    817 |         case AV_LOCK_OBTAIN:
        |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:821:14: error: 'AV_LOCK_RELEASE' was not declared in this scope
    821 |         case AV_LOCK_RELEASE:
        |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:825:14: error: 'AV_LOCK_DESTROY' was not declared in this scope
    825 |         case AV_LOCK_DESTROY:
        |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/permute_spv.cpp.o
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In constructor 'InternalFFMpegRegister::InternalFFMpegRegister()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:885:9: error: 'av_register_all' was not declared in this scope
    885 |         av_register_all();
        |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:888:9: error: 'av_lockmgr_register' was not declared in this scope
    888 |         av_lockmgr_register(&LockCallBack);
        |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/prior_box_spv.cpp.o
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In destructor 'InternalFFMpegRegister::~InternalFFMpegRegister()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:892:9: error: 'av_lockmgr_register' was not declared in this scope
    892 |         av_lockmgr_register(NULL);
        |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::open(const char*, const cv::VideoCaptureParameters&)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1000:42: error: invalid conversion from 'const AVInputFormat*' to 'AVInputFormat*' [-fpermissive]
   1000 |       input_format = av_find_input_format(entry->value);
        |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                                          |
        |                                          const AVInputFormat*
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1019:47: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1019 |         AVCodecContext* enc = ic->streams[i]->codec;
        |                                               ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1105:53: error: invalid conversion from 'const AVCodec*' to 'AVCodec*' [-fpermissive]
   1105 |                         codec = avcodec_find_decoder(enc->codec_id);
        |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                                                     |
        |                                                     const AVCodec*
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1114:61: error: invalid conversion from 'const AVCodec*' to 'AVCodec*' [-fpermissive]
   1114 |                         codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name(video_codec_param->value);
        |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                                                             |
        |                                                             const AVCodec*
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::processRawPacket()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1234:19: error: 'AVBitStreamFilter' does not name a type
   1234 |             const AVBitStreamFilter * bsf = av_bsf_get_by_name(filterName);
        |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1235:18: error: 'bsf' was not declared in this scope
   1235 |             if (!bsf)
        |                  ^~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1240:36: error: 'bsf' was not declared in this scope
   1240 |             int err = av_bsf_alloc(bsf, &bsfc);
        |                                    ^~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1240:42: error: 'bsfc' was not declared in this scope
   1240 |             int err = av_bsf_alloc(bsf, &bsfc);
        |                                          ^~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1240:23: error: 'av_bsf_alloc' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'av_max_alloc'?
   1240 |             int err = av_bsf_alloc(bsf, &bsfc);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                       av_max_alloc
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1247:19: error: 'av_bsf_init' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'av_uninit'?
   1247 |             err = av_bsf_init(bsfc);
        |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
        |                   av_uninit
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/relu_spv.cpp.o
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1263:9: error: 'bsfc' was not declared in this scope
   1263 |     if (bsfc)
        |         ^~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1271:19: error: 'av_bsf_send_packet' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'avcodec_send_packet'?
   1271 |         int err = av_bsf_send_packet(bsfc, &packet);
        |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                   avcodec_send_packet
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1277:15: error: 'av_bsf_receive_packet' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'avcodec_receive_packet'?
   1277 |         err = av_bsf_receive_packet(bsfc, &packet_filtered);
        |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |               avcodec_receive_packet
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::grabFrame()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1321:45: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1321 |     valid = avcodec_receive_frame(video_st->codec, picture) >= 0;
        |                                             ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1371:43: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1371 |         if (avcodec_send_packet(video_st->codec, &packet) < 0) {
        |                                           ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1374:47: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1374 |         ret = avcodec_receive_frame(video_st->codec, picture);
        |                                               ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1383:40: error: 'AVFrame' {aka 'struct AVFrame'} has no member named 'pkt_pts'; did you mean 'pkt_dts'?
   1383 |                 picture_pts = picture->pkt_pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE_ && picture->pkt_pts != 0 ? picture->pkt_pts : picture->pkt_dts;
        |                                        ^~~~~~~
        |                                        pkt_dts
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1383:79: error: 'AVFrame' {aka 'struct AVFrame'} has no member named 'pkt_pts'; did you mean 'pkt_dts'?
   1383 |                 picture_pts = picture->pkt_pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE_ && picture->pkt_pts != 0 ? picture->pkt_pts : picture->pkt_dts;
        |                                                                               ^~~~~~~
        |                                                                               pkt_dts
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1383:103: error: 'AVFrame' {aka 'struct AVFrame'} has no member named 'pkt_pts'; did you mean 'pkt_dts'?
   1383 |                 picture_pts = picture->pkt_pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE_ && picture->pkt_pts != 0 ? picture->pkt_pts : picture->pkt_dts;
        |                                                                                                       ^~~~~~~
        |                                                                                                       pkt_dts
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::retrieveFrame(int, unsigned char**, int*, int*, int*, int*)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1421:27: error: 'bsfc' was not declared in this scope
   1421 |             AVPacket& p = bsfc ? packet_filtered : packet;
        |                           ^~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1427:48: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1427 |             *data = ic->streams[video_stream]->codec->extradata;
        |                                                ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1428:48: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1428 |             *step = ic->streams[video_stream]->codec->extradata_size;
        |                                                ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1453:34: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1453 |         frame.width != video_st->codec->width ||
        |                                  ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1454:35: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1454 |         frame.height != video_st->codec->height ||
        |                                   ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1459:38: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1459 |         int buffer_width = video_st->codec->coded_width, buffer_height = video_st->codec->coded_height;
        |                                      ^~~~~
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/shader/softmax_spv.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/vkcom/src/buffer.cpp.o
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1463:31: error: 'buffer_height' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'buffer_width'?
   1463 |                 buffer_width, buffer_height,
        |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                               buffer_width
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1493:33: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1493 |         frame.width = video_st->codec->width;
        |                                 ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1494:34: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1494 |         frame.height = video_st->codec->height;
        |                                  ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1504:26: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1504 |             0, video_st->codec->coded_height,
        |                          ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::retrieveHWFrame(cv::OutputArray)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1533:44: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1533 |     return hw_copy_frame_to_umat(video_st->codec->hw_device_ctx, picture, output);
        |                                            ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'double CvCapture_FFMPEG::getProperty(int) const':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1569:30: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1569 |         codec_id = video_st->codec->codec_id;
        |                              ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1570:40: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1570 |         codec_tag = (double) video_st->codec->codec_tag;
        |                                        ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1590:43: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1590 |         AVPixelFormat pix_fmt = video_st->codec->pix_fmt;
        |                                           ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1599:29: error: 'bsfc' was not declared in this scope
   1599 |         const AVPacket& p = bsfc ? packet_filtered : packet;
        |                             ^~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'double CvCapture_FFMPEG::get_fps() const':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1670:52: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1670 |         fps = 1.0 / r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->codec->time_base);
        |                                                    ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'void CvCapture_FFMPEG::seek(int64_t)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1727:58: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1727 |         avcodec_flush_buffers(ic->streams[video_stream]->codec);
        |                                                          ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function 'bool icv_configure_video_stream_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, const AVCodec*, int, int, int, double, AVPixelFormat)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1962:29: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   1962 |     AVCodecContext *c = st->codec;
        |                             ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1970:5: error: 'avcodec_get_context_defaults3' was not declared in this scope
   1970 |     avcodec_get_context_defaults3(c, codec);
        |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function 'int icv_av_write_frame_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, uint8_t*, uint32_t, AVFrame*, int)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2077:35: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2077 |     AVCodecContext* c = video_st->codec;
        |                                   ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::writeFrame(const unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2176:35: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2176 |     AVCodecContext* c = video_st->codec;
        |                                   ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2254:19: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2254 |     if (video_st->codec->hw_device_ctx) {
        |                   ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2261:45: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2261 |         if (av_hwframe_get_buffer(video_st->codec->hw_frames_ctx, hw_frame, 0) < 0) {
        |                                             ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::writeHWFrame(cv::InputArray)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2290:20: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2290 |     if (!video_st->codec->hw_frames_ctx)
        |                    ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2298:41: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2298 |     if (av_hwframe_get_buffer(video_st->codec->hw_frames_ctx, hw_frame, 0) < 0) {
        |                                         ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2304:42: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2304 |     if (!hw_copy_umat_to_frame(video_st->codec->hw_device_ctx, input, hw_frame)) {
        |                                          ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'void CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2379:19: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2379 |     if( video_st->codec->pix_fmt != input_pix_fmt)
        |                   ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2391:29: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2391 |     avcodec_close(video_st->codec);
        |                             ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'bool CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::open(const char*, int, double, int, int, const cv::VideoWriterParameters&)':
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2518:26: error: invalid conversion from 'const AVOutputFormat*' to 'AVOutputFormat*' [-fpermissive]
   2518 |     fmt = av_guess_format(NULL, filename, NULL);
        |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                          |
        |                          const AVOutputFormat*
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2598:18: error: 'AVFormatContext' {aka 'struct AVFormatContext'} has no member named 'filename'
   2598 |     snprintf(oc->filename, sizeof(oc->filename), "%s", filename);
        |                  ^~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2598:39: error: 'AVFormatContext' {aka 'struct AVFormatContext'} has no member named 'filename'
   2598 |     snprintf(oc->filename, sizeof(oc->filename), "%s", filename);
        |                                       ^~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2714:58: error: 'AVFormatContext' {aka 'struct AVFormatContext'} has no member named 'filename'
   2714 |         codec_id = av_guess_codec(oc->oformat, NULL, oc->filename, NULL, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        |                                                          ^~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2732:35: error: 'AVStream' {aka 'struct AVStream'} has no member named 'codec'
   2732 |     AVCodecContext *c = video_st->codec;
        |                                   ^~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-uk1uaj8c/opencv-contrib-python_3114f56ff4ff4cd6b6c1a71aa945613a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2765:41: error: invalid conversion from 'const AVCodec*' to 'AVCodec*' [-fpermissive]
   2765 |             codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
        |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: opencv doesn't work with newest ffmpeg libraries. opencv depends on some legacy stuff still.

Comment: Can you tell me the latest version of ffmpeg that opencv works with?